# trying to execute a function that is passed to a component using context

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-context

I am trying to learn the concept of [context](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html) in react, I am trying to pass a function that closes the current user session to a component using context, I am following the context guide in the [Updating Context from a Nested Component](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html#updating-context-from-a-nested-component) section, but when clicking on the logout button I get the following message `Expected onClick listener to be a function, instead got a value of object type.`

The code is the following

I create the context with an empty function as default value

```
const LogoutContext = React.createContext(() => {});
```

The Root component has as state property that call the logout handler and I am passing as a Provider value the whole state, as I read in the documentation

```
class Root extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      username: null,
      password: null,
      currentUsername: null,
      logout: this.handleLogout 
    };

    this.handleLogout = () => {
      this.setState({ currentUsername: null });
    };    
  }

  render() {
    const currentUsername = this.state.currentUsername;

    if (currentUsername) {
      return (
        <LogoutContext.Provider value={this.state}>
          <Dashboard username={currentUsername} />
        </LogoutContext.Provider>
      );
    }

    return (
      <Login />
    );
  }
}
```

The dashboard component renders the Navbar component which is the component that receives the function using context that I need to execute

```
function Dashboard(props) {
  return (
    <div>
      <Navbar />
      <Main />
    </div>
  );
}
```

In the target component I am expecting for the function to be executed by clicking on the logout button, but instead I get the error message mentioned

```
function Navbar(props) {
  return (
    <LogoutContext.Consumer>
      {logout => (
        <nav>
          <ul>
            <li>
              <button onClick={logout}>Logout</button>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </nav>
      )}
    </LogoutContext.Consumer>
  );
}
```

I thank your observations

Comment: `createContext` expects an object, not a function returning an object. Both `React.createContext({})` and `React.createContext((() => {})())` would be valid, because they provide the expected type of argument. But, outside of that, I don't understand what you're trying to do, therefore I can't provide an answer.

Comment: thanks for answering, could you provide an example

Comment: The gist of it is `() => {}` is not equivalent with `{}` or with `(() => {})()`. First is a function returning an object ***when*** and ***if*** it is run (which never happens, unless you run it). Second and third ***are*** objects because that's what they "become" when parsed/read (because the function is run). I hope I'm being clear enough.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are 2 issues  First, you're passing the entire state object as the value of your context provider, when it seems as though you only want to pass the logout function. Second, the logout property is set on state before `this.handleLogout` is defined, so it should have a value of undefined.

State should only be used for values that are going to change through the course of the component's lifecycle. The easy fix is to just remove logout from state and pass `this.handleLogout` as your context value.

Comment: thanks Robb, applying your suggestion solved the problem